# python regex to obtain a group word as 'initial _name_'

Tags: python, regex

I have a python code which can group same words before paranthesis like `car(sedan,hatchback)` and  `car(limo)` and groups as `car(sedan,hatchback,limo)`.

But i cannot group words like `initial _name_(register,names)` and `initial _name_(surnames)` 
In my code i used a regex to match strings like 'car' but how should i do to get for `initial _name_`

My code(please correct my regex to group the word as `initial _name_` ):

```
with open('text1.txt') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\S+)\((.*)\)$') <=regex to  be used for grouping initial _name_ before (...)
    current_group = None

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members.extend(group_members.split(','))
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you mean having 2 words instead of one before the parenthesis?

Comment: yes its two words 'initial' space '_name_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would make the part `<space>_name_`  as optional, so that it would match the both formats.

```
^(\S+(?: _[^_]*_)?)\((.*)\)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vY0rD6/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^(.*?)\((.*)\)$
```

This will accept space as well.